# Allow Session to be accessible from domain.com and domain/[Account_name].com

Tags: php, session

I cannot for the life of me get a $_SESSION to be avilaible on two URLs... Which are the same domain, only there is a htaccess rewrite changing any URL with:

```
domain.com/ACCOUNT_NAME to domain/ACCOUNT_NAME.com
```

I have tried the following:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".domain.com"
```

I updated my php.ini file with the above and this did not work. I have also tried the following to no success,

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain','.domain.com');
```

Any suggestions? Or maybe I should just store the Session data in a database somehow...

Comment: surely you're talking of `ACCOUNT_NAME.domain.com`?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I rewrite the domain name to be domain/ACCOUNT_NAME.com instead of domain.com/ACCOUNT_NAME within htaccess or are your taking about .domain.com written in the ini_set?

Comment: what is `domain/ACCOUNT_NAME.com`? it's neither proper domain name nor catalog.

Comment: Would it not be a sub domain? so for example if someone had the domain pagefor.com and a user has the name bob... Then htaccess can rewrite pagefor.com/bob to pagefor/bob.com... Would that be wrong?

Comment: this never would work nor make any sense. 
The only sensible way is to have a site `bob.domain.com`, but you don't need .htaccess to achieve that.

Comment: How so? excuse my ignorance, I have managed to get this working locally... It just makes the url make more sense (It terms of pageforbob) instead of bob.pagefor.com or pagefor.com/bob ... Albeit I got it working, but dont have access the set $_session variable if a user logs in.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of domain naming is wrong.

It's impossible to have a domain name like `domain/ACCOUNT_NAME.com` - a slash is just disallowed in the domain name (not to mention that you will need to register another 2nd level domain for each user), nor it being a separator for the domain names. Even if you managed to make it work locally, you will never be able to bring such a domain name to public. Th only use for subdomains you can have in the form of `ACCOUNT_NAME.example.com`

Please, read on domain naming: [Domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name#Technical_requirements_and_process)

So, you have but 2 choices

- `example.com/bob` - you need a rewrite rule for this (the thing you called .htaccess)
- `bob.example.com` - you don't need no rewrite for this but some DNS and web-server adjustments.

And as soon as you will solve your domain naming problem, you will have your session working for all the subdomains. As it obviously works for `sub`-domains only, means `example.com` can set a cookie for `bob.example.com` but not for whatever `example.bob.com` as `bob.com` being a completely different domain.